# Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Читаю Spring in action 5, пытаюсь реализовать примеры. На одном из контроллеров выходит ошибка:

> Field error in object 'pizza' on field 'ingredients': rejected value [PFDG,CHED,KTCH]; codes [typeMismatch.pizza.ingredients,typeMismatch.ingredients,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [pizza.ingredients,ingredients]; arguments []; default message [ingredients]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'ingredients'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spring5inaction.pizzacloud.entity.Ingredient' for property 'ingredients[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]

Только осваиваю Spring, просьба подсказать в чем проблема и по возможности как ее решить?

Код контроллера:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("order")
public class DesignPizzaController {

private final IngredientRepository repository;
private final PizzaRepository pizzaRepository;

@Autowired
public DesignPizzaController(IngredientRepository repository, PizzaRepository pizzaRepository) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.pizzaRepository = pizzaRepository;
}

@ModelAttribute(name = "order")
public Order order(){return new Order();}

@ModelAttribute(name = "pizza")
public Pizza pizza(){return new Pizza();}

@GetMapping
public String showDesignForm(Model model){
    List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

    repository.findAll().forEach(i -> ingredients.add(i));

    Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
    for (Type type : types) {
        model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(), filterByType(ingredients, type));
    }

   // model.addAttribute("design", new Pizza());
    return "design";
}


//Make some errors with valid entity
@PostMapping
public String processDesign(Pizza pizza, @RequestParam("ingredients") String[] strs, @ModelAttribute Order order){

//    List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
//        for (String str : strs) {
//            System.out.println(str);
//            ingredients.add(repository.findOne(str));
//        }
//        pizza.setIngredients(ingredients);
    System.out.println(pizza);
//        Pizza saved = pizzaRepository.save(pizza);
//        order().addDesign(saved);
    return "redirect:/orders/current";
}

private List<Ingredient> filterByType(
        List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
    return ingredients
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

Код вьюшки:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
<title>Pizza cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Design your pizza:</h1>
<img th:src="@{/images/pizza.png}" width="275" height="255">
<form method="post" th:object="${pizza}">
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ingredients')}"
          th:errors="*{ingredients}">Ingredient Error</span>
<div class="grid">
<div class="ingredient-group" id="doughs">
    <h3>Designate your dough:</h3>
    <div th:each="ingredient: ${dough}">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ingredient-group" id="meats">
    <h3>Choose your meat:</h3>
    <div th:each="ingredient : ${meat}">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
    <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
    <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
    <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
    <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
        />
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
    <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
    <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
        <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
        />
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

    <h3>Name your pizza creation:</h3>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <span th:text="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}">XXX</span>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
          th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
    <br/>
    <button>Submit your pizza</button>

</form>
```

Сам класс:

```
public class Pizza {

private Long id;
private Date createdAt;
private String name;
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

public Pizza() {
}

public Pizza(String name, List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.name = name;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Pizza pizza = (Pizza) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, pizza.id) &&
            Objects.equals(createdAt, pizza.createdAt) &&
            Objects.equals(name, pizza.name) &&
            Objects.equals(ingredients, pizza.ingredients);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, createdAt, name, ingredients);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pizza{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", ingredients=" + ingredients +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: Вадим. Я тоже читаю эту книгу и столкнулся с этой же проблемой. Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее как вы решили эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'ingredients';
```

Вы передаёте массив стрингов там, где требуется List.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как передать с вьюшки List?

Comment: Можно полный  стектрейс?

Comment: Может здесь: public String processDesign(Pizza pizza, @RequestParam("ingredients") List<Ingridients> strs, @ModelAttribute Order order)

Comment: Тогда тоже ошибка, что в реквесте возвращается String[], но всеравно спасибо за советы. Решил все через @RequestParam и передачи их в конструктор.